# Do infantry units stack in Endless Legend?

Tags: endless-legend

I'm having lots of trouble stacking some infantry units in my army to make room for other units.
I know you can stack similar ranged units, but how about the infantry ?

Answer (score 8):

All types of units (Infantry, Ranged, Cavalry, Support, Flying) can be stacked into a single army, regardless of how similar they are. Unit stacking is limited to 4 by default, but is increased with military technologies which give "+x unit slot(s) on empire". Tier II - Meritocratic Promotion, and Tier IV - Signal Corps both increase the limit by 2.

Note the unit stack limit circled in the image below (beneath the army list) and the infantry (Vinesnakes) in the army.
[image]